# Is there any other way to install umbraco extensions/website utilities, other than "Umbraco package Repository" through website panel?

Tags: content-management-system, installation, extension-methods, umbraco

Is there any other way to install umbraco extensions/website utilities, other than "Umbraco package Repository" through website panel?

I wanted to install social bookmarking, however it says **"No luck!
There's no project that matches social bookmarking.
Maybe it doesn't exist, maybe it hasn't been approved yet. After all, it does take community kudos from at least 15 people to make it inside this repository"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to install a Package](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/packages-and-projects/how-to-install-a-package) in the [Umbraco Wiki](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki):

> Follow these steps to install a package into your Umbraco website:
>
> 1. Login to Umbraco
> 2. Goto the Developer section
> 3. From the tree expand the Packages folder
> 4. From here there are two ways to install a package
>
>    1. Select Install local package OR browse the Umbraco Package Respository
> 5. If you install local package, you do not unzip the package but load the zip into Umbraco.

You can find a complete listing of the available packages on the [Projects](http://our.umbraco.org/projects) section of [Our Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/).

As was stated in the message you received from the Umbraco Package Repository, only those packages that have a certain number of kudos will make it in there. The rest will need to be downloaded and installed from your local computer.